# Laravel Sail - Why do I get the laravel project directory when I access the localhost?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sail

this is a fresh install laravel app. Any idea why it shows the project directory instead of the laravel welcome view when accessing http://localhost in the browser?

What I've tried:

- I've restarted the app several times.
- I also try to use laravel built-in server by running `sail php artisan serve` but no luck.

What I haven't tried:

- Check apache2 configuration

[image: http://localhost]

Should I also file this to the laravel repository on Github?

Answer (score 1):

you should have file name **vhosts** or something like that in config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"  ->here put your root projects like this
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

In Ubuntu it is `/etc/hosts.` You can edit the file as same in other OSes

you need to write something like that

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
```

hopefully that is help you

Answer (score 0):

You should map your site to the public folder in html. In apache you do this in a .conf file inside /sites-available.